# Spark on Kubernetes - Failing to pass typesafe application.conf to driver and executor pods

Tags: java, apache-spark, kubernetes, typesafe, typesafe-config

We are migrating our Spark workloads from Cloudera to Kubernetes.

For demo purposes, we wish to run one of our spark jobs within a minikube cluster using spark-submit in cluster mode.

I would like to pass a typesafe `application.conf` file as a java option to both driver and executor jvms using the `spark.driver.defaultJavaOptions` and `spark.executor.defaultJavaOptions` --conf

The configuration file has been copied to the spark docker image at build time at the `/opt/spark/config` directory. The same docker image is used to run driver and executor pods.

application.conf is passed as follows:

```
    --conf spark.driver.defaultJavaOptions="-Dconfig.file=file://${POD_CONFIG_DIR}/application.conf $JAVA_ARGS" \
    --conf spark.executor.defaultJavaOptions="-Dconfig.file=file://${POD_CONFIG_DIR}/application.conf" \
```

where ${POD_CONFIG_DIR} is /opt/spark/config

My job doesn't work correctly, actually it takes the default values existing into `reference.conf` file. I have no io FileNotFoundExceptions though. What could I be missing ? Thank you in advance.

Here is my full spark-submit command

```
spark-submit \
        --master k8s://https://192.168.49.2:8443 \
        --driver-memory ${SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY} --executor-memory ${SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY} \
        --deploy-mode cluster \
        --class "${MAIN_CLASS}" \
        --conf spark.driver.defaultJavaOptions="-Dconfig.file=file://${POD_CONFIG_DIR}/application.conf $JAVA_ARGS" \
        --conf spark.executor.defaultJavaOptions="-Dconfig.file=file://${POD_CONFIG_DIR}/application.conf" \
        --conf spark.executor.instances=5 \
        --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=$SPARK_CONTAINER_IMAGE \
        --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
        --conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=512M \
        --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=8192M \
        --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.caCertFile=$HOME/.minikube/ca.crt \
        --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath="./" \
        local:///path/to/uber/jar/file.jar \
        "${PROG_ARGS[@]}" > $LOG_FILE 2>&1
```